# Power BI - Divide Returns 1 always

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have some measures in power BI, and for some reason, they're returning 1.

See the results below:
[image]

The leftmost Measure is supposed to be a percentage, of Measure 3 / Measure 2. Yet it's returning a 1. It seems to be rounded for some reason. Can someone explain to me why this is occurring?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was some hidden rounding. Once I set it to have some decimal places, it sorted itself.

[image]